# Race condition issue in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

I wrote a bash script that tries to send some POST requests to my website. In my POST request handler on the website I have a logic like:

```
$std = new \stdClass();
$std->ok = false;
$order = getOrderById(id); // table: orders
$user_id = user_id;
if (!empty($order)) {
    if (!orderIsntPerformedByUser($user_id, $order->id)) { // table: performed_orders
        updateUserData($user_id, ['user_balance', 'user_balance+1']); // table: users
        performOrderByUserId($order->id, $user_id); // table: performed_orders
    }
}
echo json_encode((array)$std);
return;
```

bash script:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    curl 'http://example.com/handlePostRequest' --form-data="id=1" &
done
```

It sends 5 post requests in the background and my website responses instantly. All requests execute at the same time and a few of the requests receive "true" response from the server.

I think that I need to use transaction mechanism to avoid this situation? Or how to do some delay between user requests for avoid it? What's best way to fix it?  I tried to do this action for similar websites and I got delay between a requests.

Thanks you so much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You got hit by the concurrency. You're checking the data validity in your script - that's wrong. Data is validated using the database. You got a whole bunch of false positives. The way this is done is by just inserting into the database. `order_id` is made as a unique key so if the insert with same `order_id` occurs, you update the record. MySQL's syntax for this is `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It solves all your problems. [Here's the link to MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) about the syntax I mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I'll expand on my comment. You're doing things wrong on your server. You're using PHP to validate whether the order is in the database, but the PHP script is not the data authority - MySQL is. MySQL's job is to take care of data. Your requirement is that you insert into the table, and if the record exists with that `order_id` - update the `current_balance`.

This is achieved by placing a `unique key` on `order_id`. Then your query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, current_balance) VALUES (1, 13.37) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE current_balance = current_balance + 333.333
```

Benefits of this approach:

- Database takes care of the data (that's its job)
- Concurrency problems won't occur
- Data integrity is preserved
- You have less code to take care of

Comment: Btw update user balance this way is bad architecture! This is better way:
`START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO orders (order_id, current_balance) VALUES (1, 13.37) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE current_balance = current_balance + 333.333;
INSERT INTO transaction_history ....;
COMMIT;`

Comment: @kirugan it's not bad architecture, all InnoDB tables run in autocommit mode which implies they are in their own transaction. You don't have to start one implicitly. Therefore, adding `START TRANSACTION` is useless, they're already in transaction. Do read the manual.

Comment: @N.B., sorry for incorrect description. I have a table that stores performed orders by user. I need to check if user isn't already performed an order then update his balance. Also if a certain amount of users performed a order, then I need to delete this order from the orders table.

Comment: Can you update the original question then, with all the information that you posted here? It's kind of silly that you asked something that's not really related to your problem. Also, how can several users perform the same order? I don't get that part, aren't orders unique to people? The logic remains the same in any case, you insert into orders table, on duplicate key update. You can use triggers to update people's balance when something happens on the order table (be it insert or update). That will still save you from concurrency problems and will be done by the db automatically.

Comment: @N.B., users can perform one order once. Yes, several users can perform the same order. I updated original question.

Comment: @N.B. I know about Innodb transaction capabilities, look at my queries - there are 2 different queries (1 from question and another one from myself).

Comment: @kirugan I don't know who you're battling, but if you have a better idea in mind (and you think you do) then by all means - post the answer. I referred to the *original* question. You invented a table for no reason, it's not needed and you stuck it into a transaction. I really don't want to argue with you, so if you could post your own thing and let's leave it at that.

Comment: @N.B., Do i need to use transaction in my current situation? In the performed_orders table no unique keys. It may contains a few rows with the same order_id and with the same user_id. Example table: http://pastebin.com/VF40yvFY Thanks!

Comment: Transactions are used when you want N number of queries to all succeed or for everything to fail if one fails. When you are involving one query, it's placed into its own transaction by default (it's called autocommit mode). However, the issue you are experiencing is due to data integrity being checked at PHP level and not on database level. Sadly, your table design doesn't appear to be proper for this task, you're involving an order that can span across multiple users and then you're imposing a limit of 10 - this becomes quite tricky to handle. When I get the time I'll update my answer.

Comment: @N.B., thank you for detailed answer. I think that I need to use multiple columns (user_id, order_id) as unique identifier in the performed_orders table? (Also 10 isn't constant value, you can ignore it)